# The disk “Vol” couldn’t be ejected because “Terminal” is using it

Tags: macos, terminal, external-disk, error

I have connected an External hard disk to Mac and just issued command `df -h` in terminal. When I tried to eject drive it shows the error. After closing terminal, I could eject it. But is that really needed ? I didn't open any files in external disk. `df -h` just shows disk usage of all drives. Then how come terminal uses the drive and prevent from ejecting?

`The disk “Vol” couldn’t be ejected because “Terminal” is using it`

Comment: If you didn't `cd` to the volume, how exactly did you run `df -h`?

Comment: From my root prompt. I don't think it's necessary to cd to volume for running `df -h`. It list all connected volumes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cd- change directory to the mounted filesystem then you must cd out of the filesystem before you can eject it. As an example

```
cd; diskutil eject /Volumes/<volume name>
```

cd: changes the current working directory to your home folder

diskutil: ejects the filesystem

There is one case where the tab needs to be closed. Sometimes the initial working directory is on the volume. (This can happen if you open a new tab from an existing tab that is visiting the volume.) When this happens, two processes are initially using the volume: `login`, and the shell it launches. `cd` will change the working directory in the shell, but won't affect the `login` process. The only way to make `login` stop using the volume is to close the tab.

If you're not sure which tab(s) to close, you can use `lsof`:

```
sudo lsof -a -c login /Volumes/<volume name>
```

This command will show the process IDs (and other info) for all `login` processes that have open some subdirectory of the volume. With the process ID, you can either:

- (if Terminal is configured to show the TTY name in the title):

  1. get the controlling terminal with `ps` (`ps -o tty -p <login pid(s),>`)
  2. find the relevant tabs from the Window menu
  3. close them
- more simply, shut down the relevant `login` by sending it/them a SIGHUP (`kill -HUP <login pid(s)>`)